# Reading properties from AnyObject

Tags: swift

Looking for some help on how to access the bellow properties
When I call this func

```
   func getBattInfo(){

        let blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()
        let list = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob?.takeRetainedValue())
        let batt = list?.takeRetainedValue()
        let CC = batt as AnyObject
        print(CC)
    }
```

I get this...

```
(
        {
        "Battery Provides Time Remaining" = 1;
        BatteryHealth = Good;
        BatteryHealthCondition = "";
        Current = "-1043";
        "Current Capacity" = 76;
        DesignCycleCount = 1000;
        "Hardware Serial Number" = D866434A0AZHDWC4R;
        "Is Charging" = 0;
        "Is Present" = 1;
        "Max Capacity" = 100;
        Name = "InternalBattery-0";
        "Power Source ID" = 6553699;
        "Power Source State" = "Battery Power";
        "Time to Empty" = 336;
        "Time to Full Charge" = 0;
        "Transport Type" = Internal;
        Type = InternalBattery;
    }
)
```

How can I read or access these properties?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional downcast `list` to the real static type

```
func getBattInfo(){

    let blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()
    let list = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob?.takeRetainedValue())
    if let powerSources = list?.takeRetainedValue() as? [[String:Any]] {
        for powerSource in powerSources {
           print(powerSource["Hardware Serial Number"])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is an array of dictionaries. So force-cast `CC` to that, i.e. to `[[String:Any]]`. Now you'll be able to access its elements. In your case, it has one element, `CC[0]`, which is itself a dictionary with elements like `CC[0]["BatteryHealth"]` and so on.

Comment: I see, I'll do that.